# JavaScript doesn't display as intended on HTML Site

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building an example in a book trying to learn JavaScript but for some reason it doesn't look like it reading the JS file when I run the html. What am I missing? The HTML and CSS shows up just fine, but when I try to enter new values its doesn't do anything. Its seems like its not reading the JS file. They are all in the same directory as well when ran.

```js
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
var n = 4;
var size = 10;
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

function addScore() {
  var name = $('name').value;
  var score = $('score').value;
  if (name == "" || score == "" || isNaN(score)) alert("Invalid data ");
  else if (n < size) {
    names[n] = name;
    scores[n] = score;
    n++;
  } else alert("Array already full");
}

function displayResults() {
  var h, avg, name;
  h = scores[0];
  name = names[0];
  avg = 0;
  for (z = 0; z < n; z++) {
    if (h > scores[0]) {
      h = scores[z];
      name = names[z]

    }
    avg = avg + scores[z];

  }
  avg = avg / n;
  var con = "<B>Results </b><br> Average Score= " + avg + "<br>Highest Score = " + name + " with a score of " + h;

  $('results').innerHTML = con;
}

function displayScores() {
  var con = "<tr><td colspan='2'><h2>Scores</h2></td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr> ";
  for (z = 0; z < n; z++) {
    con = con + "<tr><td>" + names[z] + "</td><td>" + scores[z] + "</td></tr>"

  }
  $('scores_table').innerHTML = con;

}

window.onload = function() {
  $("add").onclick = addScore;
  $("display_results").onclick = displayResults;
  $("display_scores").onclick = displayScores;
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

main {
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

td {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Score Array</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="test_scores.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Use a Test Score array</h1>

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>

    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input type="text" id="score"><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add to Array">
    <input type="button" id="display_results" value="Display Results">
    <input type="button" id="display_scores" value="Display Scores"><br>

    <div id="results"></div>
    <table id="scores_table"></table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected Outcome:
[image: Expect Outcome]

Comment: It works fine in a snippet, so it's not a problem with your code

Comment: you have error in console? check if the files are actual loaded with network inspector? i guess its with file:// protocoll

Comment: Umm.. sorry new to developing I just double click the html file and it pops up on google. Not sure how to trouble shoot past that. Sorry I'm new.

Comment: _"it pops up on google"_  I assume you mean the Chrome browser. [Open the developer console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) and check for errors.

Comment: I'm ashamed... just thank you. Here is what I am getting from the developer console.     test_scores.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.addScore (test_scores.js:11)

Comment: The error message does not match your code (there is no `n` on line 11). Make sure your browser is running the current version of your code. Clear the browser cache and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Upon closer inspection and learning about the exception message you're getting, you seem to be using jQuery and those jQuery selectors don't seem to be targeting valid html elements.

You need to make sure you're including the jQuery library (which you appear not to be doing) and that you're using the right syntax in your jQuery selectors, such as using $('#add') instead of $('add') and that elements have the corresponding Id associated to them. You have several problems like this in your code.

If you really want to use jQuery just add the '#' symbol before the name of each jQuery selector. I've modified the code. Upload the updated JS to your js file (without the start and close  tag) and try again.

I suggest you don't use jQuery just now and replace the jQuery selector for vanilla JS (pure JS). For that, instead replace every instance of $('...') with document.getElementById('...'), where ... is the name of your element's ID attribute.

Original answer:

With the provided information it's not possible to determine what the issue is. But you could try different things to find out.

If you're using Google Chrome browser. Google dev tools is a mandatory tool to troubleshoot, test and track your code in-browser. You can find an intro to Google Chrome Dev Tools [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

I suspect that your JS file is either not called test_scores.js or is not in the same location as your HTML file.

To test this, I suggest you try loading your JS directly in your HTML file. To achieve that just replace the line in your HTML file:

```
<script src="test_scores.js"></script>
```

with the following:

```
<script>
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
var n = 4;
var size = 10;
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

function addScore() {
  var name = $('#name').value;
  var score = $('#score').value;
  if (name == "" || score == "" || isNaN(score)) alert("Invalid data ");
  else if (n < size) {
    names[n] = name;
    scores[n] = score;
    n++;
  } else alert("Array already full");
}

function displayResults() {
  var h, avg, name;
  h = scores[0];
  name = names[0];
  avg = 0;
  for (z = 0; z < n; z++) {
    if (h > scores[0]) {
      h = scores[z];
      name = names[z]

    }
    avg = avg + scores[z];

  }
  avg = avg / n;
  var con = "<B>Results </b><br> Average Score= " + avg + "<br>Highest Score = " + name + " with a score of " + h;

  $('#results').innerHTML = con;
}

function displayScores() {
  var con = "<tr><td colspan='2'><h2>Scores</h2></td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr> ";
  for (z = 0; z < n; z++) {
    con = con + "<tr><td>" + names[z] + "</td><td>" + scores[z] + "</td></tr>"

  }
  $('#scores_table').innerHTML = con;

}

window.onload = function() {
  $("#add").onclick = addScore;
  $("#display_results").onclick = displayResults;
  $("#display_scores").onclick = displayScores;
};
</script>
```

If this doesn't solve it. Another issue could be that you're getting a cached version of your application. Try hard reloading your page (clear cache and reload) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: This method worked, but I still don't understand what is happening. The file is called test_scores.js and it is in the same directory as the css/html file. When using the developers console I get test_scores.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined at HTMLInputElement.addScore (test_scores.js:11). Which is what I used a long time ago. I cleared my cache in chrome and used other browsers and still nothing.

Comment: With that new piece of information I just realised you have many issues associated with jQuery selectors. If you're keen in using jQuery, you should take some time and go through their documentation and tutorials - https://jquery.com/

Comment: Ok, i'll take a look, still learning and going chapter by chapter in the book, but the solution was that something was cached. I did everything with clearing the cache to include just restarting the computer and bam it worked. Thank you again for the help and info!

Comment: No problem. Nothing wrong about learning. Quite on the contrary :)
I've updated my answer and the code. In this particular case you seem to be missing the library, but you actually don't need it at all. Instead of using $('...') use document.getElementById('...') and it should work ;)